# SFTP C++ library?

Tags: c++, sftp

Can anyone recommend a decent SFTP library for use with Windows C++ apps?  If a cross-platform one is available then all the better, but it's not essential.  It's for use with a commercial application, so paying for something isn't an issue.

I am using the superb [Ultimate TCP/IP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateTCPIP.aspx) library which supports FTP-S but not SFTP (yeh, I know, confusing isn't it!).

I've come across the [Chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ssh-sftp-c++.asp) library, which looks very good, but wondered if there are any others that people have used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

> libcurl is a free and easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library, supporting FTP, FTPS, HTTP, HTTPS, SCP, SFTP, TFTP, TELNET, DICT, LDAP, LDAPS and FILE. libcurl supports SSL certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading, HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, user+password authentication (Basic, Digest, NTLM, Negotiate, Kerberos4), file transfer resume, http proxy tunneling and more!
>
> libcurl is highly portable, it builds and works identically on numerous platforms, including Solaris, NetBSD, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Darwin, HPUX, IRIX, AIX, Tru64, Linux, UnixWare, HURD, Windows, Amiga, OS/2, BeOs, Mac OS X, Ultrix, QNX, OpenVMS, RISC OS, Novell NetWare, DOS and more...

Comment: Libcurl totally sucks when you want do more then a HTTP style request/response file transfer.

Comment: I've spent the last 4 hours trying to get libcurl to work with my SSH keys- the frustration I've experiences is completely unnecessary. It works fine for simple authentication but save yourself the trouble and use another library if you need anything advanced.

Comment: can you tell me how did you make it work? I have spent the last 3 days trying to build libcurl with sftp and got no success!

Answer (score 5):

[OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/) would be a good option.  It's cross-platform and comes with a BSD license, so you can use it in your commercial application without having to disclose your source code.

Comment: You can use any open source software in your commercial application, as long as you do not distribute the software. If I'm not mistaken, if you use the software in a system, and sell the system as a whole (without explicitly selling its software), you're not distributing software, so licence restrictions do not apply. Regardless, no restrictions apply for sure if you use the software yourself in a commercial application (in that case, you obviously don't distribute it, so publising source doesn't make sense).

Answer (score 5):

you can use libssh for SFTP under windows. you must have ssh.lib while compiling and ssh.dll while executing your program. It is working quite good for me. This sample code is a client using ssh1 and I am also supporting large files(4GB and more ) and Pause/resume.
The client will work with any ssh ( and/or SFTP )server. I cannot copy the entire code for you because of the limitation in message-length in stackoverflow.

```
main()
{
pSFTPConnector  sshc = new  SFTPConnector(L".\\", L"127.0.0.1", 22, L"sftpuser",L"sftppassword");  // change the hostname , port , username, password to your sftp server, your credentials

FILE *nullfile = fopen("null", "w");  
sshc->setLogFile(nullfile);
sshc->setVerbosity(SSH_LOG_DEBUG);  // you can change the verbosity as appropriate for you

int i=  sshc->InitSession();
if (i != E_OK) wprintf(L"%s",sshc->errstring.c_str() );
i=sshc->ConnectSession();
if (i != E_OK) wprintf(L"%s", sshc->errstring.c_str());

i = sshc->InitSFTP();
if (i != E_OK) wprintf(L"%s", sshc->errstring.c_str());

i = sshc->SFTPrename("renamed_myfile.txt", "myfile.txt");  //change these file names
i = sshc->Makedir("sftpdir");
i = sshc->testUploadFile("myfile2.txt", "1234567890testfile");


// change these file names to whatever appropriate


i = sshc->SFTPreget("c:\\testdir\\reget_downloaded_CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", "CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", 64 * 1024);
sshc->setBlockTransferDelay(1);

i = sshc->GetSessionStatus();
i = sshc->SFTPreput("c:\\testdir\\CentOS-6.5-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso", "reput_CentOS-6.5-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso", 64 * 1024);
i = sshc->SFTPreput("c:\\testdir\\Reget_CentOS-6.5-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso", "reput2_CentOS-6.5-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso", 64 * 1024);

if (i != E_OK) wprintf(L"%s", sshc->errstring.c_str());
delete sshc;
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

This is the class file:

```
// filename ssh.h
// SFTP Connection class with Pause/Resume largfiles capability
// uses libssh for sftp functionality.
// Author Desphilboy
// Written 21 Sep 2014




// needed include files on a windows system
// for linux, native file open and read/write functions must be changed.


#include <libssh\libssh.h>
#include <libssh\sftp.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include  <sys\types.h>
#include <sys\stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>
using namespace std;


// constant to limit length of character strings
#define SHORT_BUFF_LEN          1024
#define INITIALBLOCKTRANSDELAY          10          // mili seconds, this is the delay that we put after  each block transfer to make it posssible for network to absorb the data.




// these values will be returned by functions to report error or success
typedef enum sshconerr{
    E_OK = 1, E_SESSION_ALOC = -1, E_SSH_CONNECT_ERR = -2, E_SFTP_ALLOC = -3, E_INIT_SFTP = -4, E_CREATE_DIR = -5, E_FILEOPEN_WRITE = -6, E_WRITE_ERR = -7
    , E_FILE_CLOSE = -8, E_FILE_OPEN_READ = -9, E_INVALID_PARAMS = -10, E_SFTP_ERR = -11, E_SFTP_READ_ERR = -12, E_SFTP_READBYTES_ERR = -13, E_GET_FILEINF = -14
    , E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND = -15, E_RENAME_ERR = -16, E_MEM_ALLOC = -17, E_LOCAL_FILE_READ = -18, E_LOCAL_FILE_RDWR = -19, E_REMOTEFILE_SEEK = -20
    , E_REMOTE_FILE_OPEN = -21, E_DELETE_ERR = -22, E_RENAME_LOCAL_FILE = -23, E_LOCAL_DELETE_FILE = -24, E_FILEOPEN_RDONLY = -25, E_SFTP_READ_EOF=-26
    ,E_AUTHENTICATE=-27                 ,E_UNKNOWN=-999 } ESSHERR;


// status of transfers;
typedef enum sftpstat{ ES_DONE=0 , ES_INPROGRESS , ES_FAILED, ES_STARTING, ES_PAUSED, ES_RESUMING, ES_CANCELLED,  ES_NONE  } ESFTPSTAT;

using namespace std;




// statistics about the transfer;
typedef struct transferstatstruct {
    string remote_file_name;
    string local_file_name;
    __int64  initially_transferred;
    __int64  total_size;
    __int64  transferred;
    __int64  averagebps;
    __int64 seconds_elapsed;
    __int64     seconds_remained;
    int percent;    
    ESFTPSTAT transferstate;
} TTransStat;


#define E_SESSION_NEW   -1



// these libraries are required
#pragma comment(lib, "ssh.lib")         // for ex4ecution in windows, ssh.dll is needed




// this is the main class that does the majority of the work

typedef class CSFTPConnector{

private:

    ssh_session  session;                 // ssh session
    sftp_session sftp;                      // sftp session
    sftp_file file;                         // structure for a remote file
    FILE *localfile;                        // not used in windows but could be local file pointer in UNIX
    FILE *logfile;                          // the file for writing logs, default is set to stderr
    string filename;                        // file name of the transfer;
    string localfilename;                   // file name of local file;
    string      tempfilename;               // a temporaty file name will be used during the transfer which is renamed when transfer is completed.
    ESFTPSTAT transferstatus;               // state of the transfer which has one of the above values (ESFTPSTAT)

    __int64 transferstarttime;              // time of start of the transfer
    wchar_t username[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    wchar_t password[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    wchar_t hostname[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];       // hostname of the sftp server
    wchar_t basedir[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];        // this base dir is the directory of public and private key structur ( NOT USED IN THIS VERSION)
    int port;                               //  port of the server;
    int verbosity;                          //  degree of verbosity of libssh
    __int64  filesize;                      //  total number of bytes to be transfered;
    DWORD  local_file_size_hiDWORD;         //  Bill Gates cannot accept the file size without twisting the programmers, so he accepts them in 2 separate words like this
    DWORD  local_file_size_lowDWORD;        //  these 2 DWORDs when connected together comprise a 64 bit file size.
    __int64 lfilesize;                          // local file size
    __int64 rfilesize;                          // remote file size
    __int64 transfered;                         // number of bytes already transfered
    __int64 initially_was_transferred;          // this is the number of bytes which was transferred before pause or interrupt of a transfer and used when resuming a transfer.
    bool pause;                                 // pause flag
    TTransStat stats;                           // statistics of the transfer
    HANDLE  localfilehandle;                    // windows uses handles to manipulate files. this is the handle to local file.
    int blocktransferdelay;

    ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::rwopen_existing_SFTPfile(char *fn);         // open a file on remote ( server ) read/write   for upload
    ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::rdopen_existing_SFTPfile(char *fn);         // open a file on remote ( server ) read only    for download
    ESSHERR createSFTPfile(char *fn);                                   // create a file on server;
    ESSHERR writeSFTPfile(char *block, size_t blocksize);               // write a block of data to the  open remote file
    ESSHERR readSFTPfile(char *block, size_t len, size_t *bytesread);   // read a block of data from the  open remote file
    ESSHERR readSFTPfile(char *block, __int64 len, DWORD *bytesread);
    ESSHERR closeSFTPfile();        // closes the remote file;
    ESSHERR openSFTPfile(char *fn);  // opens the remote file
    ESSHERR getSFTPfileinfo();          // gets information about the remote file


public:
    wstring errstring;      // the string describing last error 
    ESSHERR Err;                // error code of last error
    CSFTPConnector();           // default constructor;
    CSFTPConnector(wchar_t *dir, wchar_t *hn, int hostport, wchar_t *un, wchar_t *pass);  // constructor
    void setVerbosity(int v);       
    int  getVerbosity();
    ESSHERR InitSession();          // must be called befor doing any transfer
    ESSHERR ConnectSession();       // connnects to the  ssh server
    ESSHERR InitSFTP();     // must be called befor doing any transfer
    ESSHERR Makedir(char *newdir);
    ESSHERR testUploadFile(char *fn, char *block);          // do not use this , only for test purposes for myself
    ESSHERR SFTPput(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize);            // Upload a file from start
    ESSHERR SFTPreput(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize);          // checks for previouse interrupted transfer, then either continues the previouse transfer ( if there was any) or starts a new one (UPLOAD)
    ESSHERR SFTPrename(char *newname, char *oldname);                   // renames a remote file( must be closed)
    ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPdelete(char *remfile);                  // deletes a remote file
    TTransStat *getStatus();                                                // gets statistics of the transfer
    ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPget(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize);    // Downloads a file from  sftp server
    ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPreget(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize);  // checks for previouse interrupted transfer, then either continues the previouse transfer ( if there was any) or starts a new one (DOWNLOAD)
    void    CancelTransfer();
    void    PauseTransfer();
    void    setLogFile(FILE *logf);         // sets the log file, if not set stderr will be used. by default.
    void    CloseLocalFile();
    void    CloseRemoteFile();
    int GetSessionStatus();
    bool  IsConnected(); 
    void setBlockTransferDelay(int miliseconds);
    ESFTPSTAT getTransferStatus();
    ~CSFTPConnector();




} SFTPConnector, *pSFTPConnector ;



sftpstat CSFTPConnector::getTransferStatus()
{
    return  transferstatus;
}


void CSFTPConnector::setBlockTransferDelay(int miliseconds)
{
    blocktransferdelay = miliseconds;

}


bool CSFTPConnector::IsConnected()
{
    if (ssh_is_connected(session) == 1) return true;
    return false;
}



int CSFTPConnector::GetSessionStatus()
{
    return ssh_get_status(session);
}

void    CSFTPConnector::CloseLocalFile()
{
    CloseHandle(localfilehandle);
}


void    CSFTPConnector::CloseRemoteFile()
{
    sftp_close(file);
}



void    CSFTPConnector::setLogFile(FILE *logf)
{
    logfile = logf;
}


void    CSFTPConnector::CancelTransfer()
{
    transferstatus = ES_CANCELLED;

}
void    CSFTPConnector::PauseTransfer()
{
    transferstatus = ES_PAUSED;
    pause = true;
}

//----------------------------------------

// SFTPreger starts or resumes a download.
ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPreget(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize)
{
    ESSHERR     result;
    int rc;
    BOOL  bresult;
    DWORD bytesread;
    DWORD byteswritten;
    filesize = 0;
    transfered = 0;
    initially_was_transferred = 0;
    lfilesize = rfilesize = 0;
    pause = false;
    transferstatus = ES_NONE;
    char *block;
    struct stat st;
    wchar_t temp[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    size_t tempsize;
    wstring wlfn;
    int loopcounter = 0;

    localfilename = lfn;
    filename = rfn;

    tempfilename = string(lfn) + ".sftp_temp";
    mbstowcs_s(&tempsize, temp, tempfilename.c_str(), SHORT_BUFF_LEN);

    localfilehandle = CreateFile(temp, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (localfilehandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        errstring = L"Could not open local file:" + wstring(temp) +L" for read and write";
        Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_RDWR;
        return E_LOCAL_FILE_RDWR;
    }
    local_file_size_lowDWORD = GetFileSize(localfilehandle, &local_file_size_hiDWORD);
    lfilesize = (local_file_size_hiDWORD * 0x100000000) + local_file_size_lowDWORD;

    if (lfilesize < 0) {
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
        errstring = L"Could not get size info for file:" + wstring(temp); 
        CloseLocalFile();
        return E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
    }

    transfered = lfilesize;
    initially_was_transferred = lfilesize;

    __int64 tempi64 = transfered & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;
    DWORD dwlow = tempi64;
    tempi64 = (transfered  & 0x7FFFFFFF00000000);
    tempi64 = tempi64 >> 32;
    long  dwhi = tempi64;
    DWORD dwResult = SetFilePointer(localfilehandle, dwlow, &dwhi, FILE_BEGIN);
    if (dwResult == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
    {
        errstring = L"could not set file pointer for localfile" + wstring(temp);
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED; Err = result; 
        CloseLocalFile();
        return result;
    }

    block = (char*)malloc(blocksize + 1);
    if (block == NULL) {
        Err = E_MEM_ALLOC;
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        errstring = L"Could not allocate memory for file block size";
        CloseLocalFile();
        return E_MEM_ALLOC;
    }

    result = rdopen_existing_SFTPfile((char *)rfn);

    if (result == E_OK){
        getSFTPfileinfo();
        filesize = rfilesize;       
    }
    else
    {
        Err = E_REMOTE_FILE_OPEN;
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        errstring = L"Could not open remote file";
        CloseLocalFile();
        delete block;
        return E_REMOTE_FILE_OPEN;
    }


    rc=sftp_seek64(file, transfered);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        Err = E_REMOTEFILE_SEEK;
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        errstring = L"Could not set pointer for remote file";
        CloseRemoteFile();
        CloseLocalFile();
        delete block;
        return E_REMOTEFILE_SEEK;
    }

        transferstatus = ES_RESUMING;


    sftp_file_set_blocking(file);

    transferstarttime = time(NULL);
    transferstatus = ES_INPROGRESS;

    while (transferstatus != ES_FAILED && transferstatus != ES_PAUSED &&  transferstatus!=ES_CANCELLED  &&transferstatus != ES_DONE)
    {
        loopcounter++;

        result = readSFTPfile(block,blocksize, (size_t *) &bytesread);
        if (result != E_OK && result != E_SFTP_READ_EOF)
        {
            errstring = L"Error reading from remote sftp server file.";
            Err = result;
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
            CloseRemoteFile();
            CloseLocalFile();
            delete block;
            return result;
        }
        if (result == E_SFTP_READ_EOF)  transferstatus = ES_DONE;
        fprintf(logfile, "Read %d bytes from input file. Number of packets: %d , %llu from %llu bytes\n", bytesread, loopcounter, transfered, filesize);

        bresult = WriteFile(localfilehandle, (LPVOID)block, bytesread, &byteswritten, NULL);
        if (byteswritten < bytesread)
        {
            if (bresult == FALSE)
            {
                errstring = L"Error writing to local file.";
                Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_RDWR;
                transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
                CloseRemoteFile();
                CloseLocalFile();
                delete block;
                return E_LOCAL_FILE_RDWR;
            }
            else if (bytesread == 0)
            {
                errstring = L"Transfer done.";
                Err = E_OK;
                transferstatus = ES_DONE;
                continue;
            }
        }


        Err = E_OK;

        if (pause == true) transferstatus = ES_PAUSED;
        if (bresult == TRUE &&  bytesread == 0)
        {
            // at the end of the file
            transferstatus = ES_DONE;
        }
        Sleep(blocktransferdelay);
        if (loopcounter % 71 == 0)Sleep(7 * blocktransferdelay);
        if (loopcounter % 331 == 0)Sleep(77 * blocktransferdelay);
        if (loopcounter % 3331 == 0)Sleep(777 * blocktransferdelay);

    }
    result = closeSFTPfile();
    CloseHandle(localfilehandle);
    Sleep(1000);

    if (transferstatus == ES_DONE)
    {
        wchar_t temp2[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
        mbstowcs_s(&tempsize, temp2, lfn, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
        bresult = MoveFile(temp, temp2);
        if (bresult != TRUE)
        {
            Err = E_RENAME_LOCAL_FILE;
            errstring = L"Could not rename local file: " + wstring(temp);
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
            delete block;
            return E_RENAME_LOCAL_FILE;
        }
    }

    if (transferstatus == ES_CANCELLED)
    {
        wchar_t temp2[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
        mbstowcs_s(&tempsize, temp2, lfn, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
        bresult = DeleteFile(temp);
        if (bresult != TRUE)
        {
            Err = E_LOCAL_DELETE_FILE;
            errstring = L"Could not rename local file: " + wstring(temp);
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
            delete block;
            return E_LOCAL_DELETE_FILE;
        }
    }

    delete block;
    return result;
}




//---------------------------------------



TTransStat * CSFTPConnector::getStatus()
{
    stats.seconds_elapsed = time(NULL); 
    stats.seconds_elapsed -= transferstarttime;
    stats.averagebps = ((transfered- initially_was_transferred) * 8) / stats.seconds_elapsed;
    if (filesize > 0) {
        stats.percent = (transfered *100)/ filesize;
        stats.seconds_remained = ((filesize - transfered) * 8) / stats.averagebps;
    }
    else
    {
        stats.percent = -1;
        stats.seconds_remained = -1;
    }
    stats.total_size = filesize;
    stats.transferstate = transferstatus;
    stats.remote_file_name = filename;
    stats.local_file_name = localfilename;
    stats.transferred = transfered;
    stats.initially_transferred = initially_was_transferred;


    return &stats;
}


ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPrename(char *newname, char *oldname)
{

    int rc=sftp_rename(sftp, oldname, newname);
    if (rc !=SSH_OK){
        return E_RENAME_ERR;
    }

    return E_OK;
}



ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPdelete(char *remfile)
{

    int rc = sftp_unlink(sftp,remfile);
    if (rc != SSH_OK){
        return E_DELETE_ERR;
    }

    return E_OK;
}

// SFTPreput
ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPreput(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize)
{
    ESSHERR     result;
    BOOL  bresult;
    DWORD bytesread;
    filesize = 0;
    transfered = 0;

    pause = false;
    transferstatus = ES_NONE;
    char *block;
    struct stat st;
    wchar_t temp[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    size_t tempsize;
    wstring wlfn;
    int loopcounter = 0;

    localfilename = lfn;
    //wlfn = wstring(lfn);
    //localfile = fopen(lfn, L"r");
    filename = rfn;
    mbstowcs_s(&tempsize, temp, lfn, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);

    //filesize = getFileSize(localfilename);

    /*if(filesize < 0) {
    transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
    Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
    return E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
    }*/

    localfilehandle = CreateFile(temp, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (localfilehandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
        return E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
    }
    local_file_size_lowDWORD = GetFileSize(localfilehandle, &local_file_size_hiDWORD);
    filesize = (local_file_size_hiDWORD * 0x100000000) + local_file_size_lowDWORD;

    if (filesize < 0) {
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
        CloseLocalFile();
        return E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
    }

    block = (char*)malloc(blocksize + 1);
    if (block == NULL) {
        Err = E_MEM_ALLOC;
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        errstring = L"Could not allocate memory for file block size";
        CloseLocalFile();
        return E_MEM_ALLOC;
    }


    tempfilename = string(rfn) + ".sftp_temp";

    result = rwopen_existing_SFTPfile((char *)tempfilename.c_str());
    if (result == E_OK){
        getSFTPfileinfo();
        sftp_seek64(file, rfilesize);
        __int64 tempi64 = rfilesize & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;
        DWORD dwlow = tempi64;
        tempi64 = (rfilesize & 0x7FFFFFFF00000000);
        tempi64 = tempi64 >> 32;
        long  dwhi = tempi64;
        DWORD dwResult=SetFilePointer(localfilehandle, dwlow,&dwhi , FILE_BEGIN);
        if (dwResult == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
        {
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED; Err = result;  return result;
        }
        transferstatus = ES_RESUMING;
        transfered = rfilesize;
        initially_was_transferred = rfilesize;

    }
    else{
        result = createSFTPfile((char *)tempfilename.c_str());
        transferstatus = ES_STARTING;
        rfilesize = 0;
        initially_was_transferred = 0;
        if (result != E_OK)  {
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED; 
            Err = result;
            CloseLocalFile();
            return result;
        }
        }
        sftp_file_set_blocking(file);
        transferstarttime = time(NULL);
        transferstatus = ES_INPROGRESS;

    while (transferstatus != ES_FAILED && transferstatus != ES_PAUSED && transferstatus != ES_DONE)
    {
        loopcounter++;
        bresult = ReadFile(localfilehandle, (LPVOID)block, blocksize, &bytesread, NULL);
        fprintf(logfile, "Read %d bytes from input file. Number of packets: %d , %llu from %llu bytes\n", bytesread, loopcounter, transfered, filesize);
        if (bytesread < blocksize)
        {
            if (bresult == FALSE)
            {
                errstring = L"Error reading from local file.";
                Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_READ;
                transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
                CloseRemoteFile();
                CloseLocalFile();
                return E_LOCAL_FILE_READ;
            }
            else if (bytesread == 0)
            {
                errstring = L"Transfer done.";
                Err = E_OK;
                transferstatus = ES_DONE;
                continue;
            }
        }

        result = writeSFTPfile(block, bytesread);
        if (result != E_OK && bytesread>0 )
        {
            errstring = L"Error transmitting to remote sftp server file.";
            Err = result;
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
            CloseRemoteFile();
            CloseLocalFile();
            return result;
        }


        Err = E_OK;
        //transfered = transfered + bytesread;
        if (pause == true) transferstatus = ES_PAUSED;
        if (bresult == TRUE &&  bytesread == 0)
        {
            // at the end of the file
            transferstatus = ES_DONE;
        }
        Sleep(blocktransferdelay);
        if (loopcounter % 71 == 0)Sleep(7 * blocktransferdelay);
        if (loopcounter % 331 == 0)Sleep(77 * blocktransferdelay);
        if (loopcounter % 3331 == 0)Sleep(777 * blocktransferdelay);

    }

    CloseRemoteFile();
    CloseLocalFile();
    Sleep(1000);

    if (transferstatus == ES_CANCELLED)
    {
        result = SFTPdelete((char *)tempfilename.c_str());
        if (bresult != E_OK)
        {
            Err = E_DELETE_ERR;
            errstring = L"Could not delete remote file.";
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
            return E_DELETE_ERR;
        }
    }
    if (transferstatus == ES_DONE) result = SFTPrename(rfn, (char *)tempfilename.c_str());
    delete block;
    return result;
}




ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::getSFTPfileinfo()
{
    sftp_attributes fileinf = sftp_fstat(file);

    if (fileinf == NULL){
        return E_GET_FILEINF;
    }

    rfilesize = fileinf->size;

    sftp_attributes_free(fileinf);
    return E_OK;
}

ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::closeSFTPfile()
{
    int rc = sftp_close(file);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't close the written file: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        return E_FILE_CLOSE;
    }
    return E_OK;
}




ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::writeSFTPfile(char *block, size_t blocksize)
{
    size_t nwritten = sftp_write(file, block, blocksize);
    if (nwritten != blocksize)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't write data to file: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        //sftp_close(file);
        transfered = transfered + nwritten;
        return E_WRITE_ERR;
    }

    transfered = transfered + nwritten;
    return E_OK;
}
ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::readSFTPfile(char *block, __int64 len, DWORD *bytesread)
{
    DWORD readbytes;
    *bytesread = 0;
    if (len <= 0) return E_INVALID_PARAMS;
    if (bytesread == NULL || block == NULL) return E_INVALID_PARAMS;

    readbytes = sftp_read(file, block, len);
    if (readbytes < 0)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't read  from  remote file: %s  %s\n", filename.c_str(), ssh_get_error(session));
        *bytesread = 0;
        return E_SFTP_READ_ERR;
    }


    if (readbytes <  len)
    {
        *bytesread = readbytes;
        return E_SFTP_READ_EOF;
    }


    *bytesread = readbytes;
    transfered = transfered + readbytes;

    return E_OK;

}


ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::createSFTPfile(char *fn)
{

    int access_type = O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND;
    int rc, nwritten;

    filename = string(fn);
    file = sftp_open(sftp, fn,access_type,  S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't open file for writing: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        return E_FILEOPEN_WRITE;
    }
    return E_OK;
}





ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::openSFTPfile(char *fn)
{
    int access_type = O_RDONLY;
    int rc, nwritten;

    filename = string(fn);
    file = sftp_open(sftp, fn,
        access_type, S_IWRITE);
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't open file for writing: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        return E_FILE_OPEN_READ;
    }
    return E_OK;

}

ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::Makedir(char *newdir)
{
    int rc;
    rc = sftp_mkdir(sftp, newdir, S_IFDIR);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        if (sftp_get_error(sftp) != SSH_FX_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS)
        {
            fprintf(logfile, "Can't create directory: %s\n",
                ssh_get_error(session));
            return E_CREATE_DIR;
        }
    }

        return E_OK;
}




SFTPConnector::CSFTPConnector()
{
    //libssh2_init(0);
    session = ssh_new();
    if (session == NULL)
    {
        Err = E_SESSION_ALOC;
        errstring = L"Could not allocate a session.";

    }
    wcscpy(hostname, L"localhost" );
    wcscpy(username, L"User");
    wcscpy(password, L"Password");
    wcscpy(basedir, L".\\");
    port = 22;
    verbosity = SSH_LOG_RARE;
    filesize = 0;
    transfered = 0;

    pause = false;
    transferstatus = ES_NONE;
    logfile = stderr;
    blocktransferdelay = INITIALBLOCKTRANSDELAY;

}




CSFTPConnector::CSFTPConnector(wchar_t *dir, wchar_t *hn, int hostport, wchar_t *un, wchar_t *pass)
{

    //libssh2_init(0);
    session = ssh_new();

    if (session == NULL)
    {
        Err = E_SESSION_ALOC;
        errstring = L"Could not allocate a session.";

    }
    wcscpy(hostname, hn);
    wcscpy(username, un);
    wcscpy(password, pass);
    wcscpy(basedir, dir);
    port = hostport;
    verbosity = SSH_LOG_RARE;
     filesize=0;
     transfered=0;

     pause=false;
     transferstatus = ES_NONE;
     logfile = stderr;
     blocktransferdelay = INITIALBLOCKTRANSDELAY;

}


ESSHERR  CSFTPConnector::InitSFTP()
{
    int rc;
    sftp= sftp_new(session);
    if (session == NULL)
    {
        Err = E_SFTP_ALLOC;
        errstring = L"Could not allocate a sftp session.";

    }

    rc = sftp_init(sftp);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Error initializing SFTP session: %s.\n",
            sftp_get_error(sftp));
        sftp_free(sftp);
        return E_INIT_SFTP;
    }


    return E_OK;
}


ESSHERR  CSFTPConnector::ConnectSession()
{
    char temp[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    size_t n_of_chars;
    wcstombs_s(&n_of_chars, temp, SHORT_BUFF_LEN, (const wchar_t *)password, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
    int ir;

    ir=ssh_connect(session);
    if (ir != SSH_OK){
        errstring = L"Could not connect the ssh session.";
        return E_SSH_CONNECT_ERR;
    }

    ir=ssh_userauth_password(session, NULL, temp);
    if (ir != SSH_OK){
        errstring = L"Could not authenticate with the ssh server.\r\n";
        return E_AUTHENTICATE;
    }
    return E_OK;
}


ESSHERR  CSFTPConnector::InitSession()
{
    char temp[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    size_t n_of_chars;
    wcstombs_s(&n_of_chars, temp,SHORT_BUFF_LEN, (const wchar_t *) hostname, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST,temp);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
    wcstombs_s(&n_of_chars, temp, SHORT_BUFF_LEN, (const wchar_t *)username, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER,temp);
    wcstombs_s(&n_of_chars, temp, SHORT_BUFF_LEN, (const wchar_t *)basedir, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_SSH_DIR, temp);

    return E_OK;
}


void  CSFTPConnector::setVerbosity(int v)
{
    verbosity = v;
}


int  CSFTPConnector::getVerbosity()
{
    return verbosity;
}
```