# Network file transfer in Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, network-programming

I want to transfer files across the network using C or C++.  What topics should I look up?  How can I do this?

Comment: Not that I feel confident that I'll be able to answer the question anyway, but...  this question sounds lacking in detail.

Comment: Across *what* network? If possible, just create a network share and copy the files across like you would anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could use [`ReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28VS.85%29.aspx) to read the file's contents and then send it over a socket, Windows also provides the [`TransmitFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740565%28VS.85%29.aspx) API to enable you to read a file's data and send it over a socket with one system call.

Comment: TransmitFile only transmit the contents of file.

Comment: It also allows you to prepend and append data to the file contents (such as an HTTP header). This is what IIS does.

Answer (score 3):

You should start by choosing a protocol.  [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) and [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol) are both good choices, but there are obviously others.  Once you have that straight, you can look up choices for client and server libraries.

Comment: FTP is insecure, and should be used only inside a firewall, or over a secure layer (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS)

Comment: the OP doesn't necessarily need to encrypt the transmitted data.

Comment: @tusbar: if you have secure libraries, why not use them?  For completeness, there's also scp.  libcurl was suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360259/sftp-c-library/360276#360276

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking through documentation of [Windows Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740673(VS.85).aspx) and [boost asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Answer (score 0):

there is sendfile function in C. Just check it out.